# Evaluate $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{1}{h^3e^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{h^2}}}}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, multivariable-calculus

Background: I need to find if \begin{cases}
\frac{1}{x^2+y^2+z^2}e^{-\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}}, \text{     }(x,y,z)\neq (0,0,0)\\
0,\text{     } (x,y,z)=(0,0,0)
\end{cases}

Differentiable at $(0,0)$

So I found that the function is continues at (0,0,0) and now I am checking if there are partial derivatives

a. why we must derive by definition?

So I derived by definition and got

$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{1}{h^3e^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{h^2}}}}$$

I would use substitution to get to an expression of the form $\frac{t^3}{e^t}$ but I have even and odd powers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\lim_{h\rightarrow 0^{+}}\dfrac{1}{h^{3}e^{1/h}}&=\lim_{u\rightarrow\infty}\dfrac{u^{3}}{e^{u}}\\
&=\lim_{u\rightarrow\infty}\dfrac{3u^{2}}{e^{u}}\\
&=\lim_{u\rightarrow\infty}\dfrac{6u}{e^{u}}\\
&=\lim_{u\rightarrow\infty}\dfrac{6}{u}\\
&=0,
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
\lim_{h\rightarrow 0^{-}}\dfrac{1}{h^{3}e^{-1/h}}&=\lim_{u\rightarrow\infty}-\dfrac{u^{3}}{e^{u}}\\
&=-\lim_{u\rightarrow\infty}\dfrac{u^{3}}{e^{u}}\\
&=0.
\end{align*}

Comment: Why it the limit $h\to 0^{-}$ the minus sign in the exponent got out to the fraction?

Comment: Because we let $u=-1/h$, so $1/h^{3}=-u^{3}$.

Answer (score 2):

You need to differentiate by definition, because you have no formula for the function at zero and including neighbourhoods.

For your limit, 
$$
\lim_{h\to0^+}\frac{1}{h^3e^{1/|h|}}
=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x^3}{e^{x}}=0,
$$
easily done by L'Hôpital. Similarly, $$\lim_{h\to0^-}\frac{1}{h^3e^{1/|h|}}=0.$$

Answer (score 2):

The story for **Differentiability and Continuity** for functions of several variables is as follow:

**1.** If a function is discontinuos then it can't be differentiable, infact *continuity is a necessary condition since differentiability implies continuity*.

**2.** If partial derivatives do not exist then $f$ can't be
        differentiable, infact *existence of partial derivatives is a necessary condition since differentiability implies their existence*.

**3.** If partial derivatives exist and are continuos you are done, infact for the **"Differentiability theorem"** if all the partial derivatives exist and are continuous in a neighborhood of the point then (i.e. sufficient condition) the function is differentiable at that point.

**4.** If partial derivatives are not continuos at the point you can't yet
    conclude anything about differentiability. You need to **check
    directly differentiability by definition** that:

$$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{\| f(h)-f(0)-\Delta f(0)\cdot h\|}{\|h\|}=0$$

In this case by the limit you can easy verify that partial derivatives are $0$ at $(x,y,z)=(0,0,0)$ and you can conclude by definition according to point **4** .

Answer (score 0):

Separating the cases for positive and negative $h$, we get rid of the square root:

$$
\lim_{h\to 0^+}{\frac{1}{h^3 e^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{h^2}}}}}=\lim_{h\to 0^+}{e^{-\ln(h^3)- \frac{1}{h}}}
$$

$$
\lim_{h\to 0^-}{\frac{1}{h^3 e^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{h^2}}}}}=\lim_{h\to 0^-}{-e^{-\ln(-h^3)+ \frac{1}{h}}}
$$

Evaluating:

$$
\lim_{h\to 0^+} \left( {-\ln(h^3)- \frac{1}{h}} \right)
$$

And:
$$
\lim_{h\to 0^-} \left( {-\ln(-h^3)+ \frac{1}{h}} \right)
$$
Note that:

$$
\lim_{x\to 0}  x\ln(x)  = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\ln(x)}{1/x}=\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1/x}{-1/x^2}=\lim_{x\to 0} (-x)=0 
$$

Then:
$$
\lim_{h\to 0^+} \left( {-\ln(h^3)- \frac{1}{h}} \right) = \lim_{h\to 0} -\frac{3h\ln (h)+1}{h}= -\infty
$$

And
$$
\lim_{h\to 0^-} \left( {-\ln(-h^3)+ \frac{1}{h}} \right) = \lim_{h\to 0} -\frac{3h\ln (h)-1}{h} = -\infty
$$

In both cases the original limit is of the form $e^{-\infty}=0$ because the inverse square root term dominates over the logaritmic term.